# New CPU Fan/Heat Sink recommendation

Tags: processor, motherboard, cooling, heat-sink

I'm looking for a recommendation of a quiet fan/heat sink for an AMD A8-3870K CPU on a Gigabyte [GA-A75M-UD2H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A75M-UD2H-rev-10#ov) mobo. Mine is about 9 years old and it's getting loud.

I've cleaned dust out of the case, removed the CPU fan/heatsink, blown it out, and applied new thermal paste, yet I still have noise issues.

Edit: As it is an older machine, I don't want to spend too much. If possible, I'd like to keep it around $20.

Comment: Any clearance issues with particularly high memory modules, or a tiny case? If it's just the fan speed being higher than usual, replacing the thermal paste should do the trick. After 9 years, it will be dried out. If the fan itself is making weird noises due to a bearing failure, you could just replace the fan. Which CPU cooler are you using right now?

Comment: @MechEng He did replace thermal compound as noted in his original post at  https://superuser.com/questions/1542213/cpu-fan-surges-frequently

Comment: It may be possible to replace just the fan, if you provide a clear picture of the fan showing its make and model, and dimensions of the screw positions. That would radically reduce the cost of replacement.  Also, please provide the space available, all three dimensions, within the case, for a replacement heatsink/fan combination. Note: The AMD A8-3870K CPU https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a8-series-apu-for-desktops/a8-3870k-radeon-hd-6550d has a TDP of 100W and uses an FM1 socket.

Answer (score 2):

Before we leave you hanging there, I'll give it a shot.
Combining the information you gave here and over on Superuser, a new fan probably won't cut it. Either your current cooler does not have enough thermal mass, or maybe the heatpipes have leaked. If it has any...

Assuming you have enough clearance for a small tower cooler in your case (please check before buying, or add the case to your question), this is the cheapest option I would recommend:
https://www.lc-power.com/en/product/cpu-cooler/lc-cc-95/
It starts at 11€ plus shipping in Germany. The fan is PWM controlled, your motherboard has a PWM fan header for the CPU. It is rated for up to 130W TDP, although I find these ratings rather meaningless. What's important is that it is a tower cooler with 2 heatpipes and a relatively quiet fan.

If you want to step it up a notch, or can't find this cooler anywhere, here are a few alternatives, in ascending order of price, and to some extent quality:
https://www.xilence.net/en/cpu-coolers/30
https://www.arctic.ac/de_en/freezer-13.html
https://www.alpenfoehn.de/en/products/cpu-cooler/bennevis
https://www.bequiet.com/en/cpucooler/532